# SSRS whether exist internal scripts

Tags: reporting-services

In other products Microsoft like Excel exists VBA. If I use it I can make changes with tables (like merge cells, set value one column as sum values from other).
Whether exist internal scripts in SSRS like VBA that give opportunity make changes with tables? If exists, give a link.

(I googled this, but I found only external scripts for engine report placing from the server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSRS you can set programmatically a lot of presentation settings like colors, sizes, formats, etc. using [Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) which are written in Microsoft Visual Basic. Also you can modify the underlying data using expressions to compute information you want to show in your report.

There are plenty VB functions implemented in SSRS Expressions but you can also extend the behaviour of your reports by using [Custom Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx) to implement your own functions.

Let me know if this helps.